# add block before footer - magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, blocks

I have add one block in product detail page. I am trying to position the block before footer but its not work.

```
<container name="chennai.review" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="review" before="footer-container">
<block class="Gworks\About\Block\Review" name="chennai.review.info" template="Gworks_About::review.phtml"/>
</container>
```

expected result

[image: this]

why my code is not working,How to achieve?

Comment: Is it injecting the contents of that container anywhere on the page?  Just in the wrong location?

Comment: sorry I can't get clear, could you explain more

Answer (score 8):

One possible solution to your issue:

Instead of using the before attribute on your new container (I have not seen the most consistent results using this), Just add your new container node inside the `page.bottom.container` container.

This should look something like:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
    <container name="chennai.review" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="review">
        <block class="Gworks\About\Block\Review" name="chennai.review.info" template="Gworks_About::review.phtml"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Then you can remove the before attribute all together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. your code working after put some css work! first its look like strange. I am looking for reason why before attribute not working for me, if you update, tick your answer. now upvote you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the contents of `<your Magento install dir>/pub/static` folder.

Run the static view files deployment tool `<your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

or

Run the below command:

```
<your Magento install dir>php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy    
<your Magento install dir>php bin/magento indexer:reindex
<your Magento install dir>php bin/magento cache:flush
```

May that solve your problem

Comment: before itself I try this no luck, are you sure my method is right? because position only the problem, contents get reflecting successfully

Answer (score 0):

```
remove any folder from <your Magento install dir>/var/cache/
remove **view_preprocessed** folder from <your Magento install dir>/var/
remove all folder (frontend) rom <your Magento install dir>/pub/static/
```

Now refresh the page, your changes will be there, otherwise there is some problem in your code.